# Is there a way to stop tests running from base class, but still let these tests run from its subclass in Java?

Tags: java, testing, subclass, base-class

I have a set of tests in class A, and class B extends this class.
In Java, can we let these tests only run from class B and not from class A?

Comment: make `A` abstract

Comment: Thank you. I tested and it worked. Why does this work?

Comment: added this as an answer with a hopefully understandable explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by making class `A` abstract. The test runner cannot instantiate the abstract class, so it will not run the tests for `A`. But when inspecting class `B` it detects the methods from the base class and as these are valid to be called from the derived class `B` it invokes them.

You can use this to define test methods in `A` and derive classes `B` and `C` from `A`. In the derived classes you can provide a different setups like connections to other services for example and then use the same tests for both setups.